# Getting two errors in the code with the UIWebViewDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a problem with this code:

Header:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *field;
    IBOutlet UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate> *web;
}
```

Implementation:

```
@protocol UIWebViewDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    //some other code here
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    webView.delegate = self; 
}
```

I got two problems. The first is that on the line `webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];</code>the compiler generates the following message:Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIWebView*_strong' from 'UIWebView'*'.

The second problem is that I get an error on the line <code>webView.delegate = self;</code> that says:`
'Passing ViewController*const_strong to parameter of incompatible type 'id'`.

Any ideas? Any help will be welcome.

Comment: What is the declaration of those ivars?

Comment: Now it's just [super viewDidLoad];.

Comment: I mean the declaration of the instance variables in the interface...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your `webView` ivar to be a `UIWebViewDelegate`. You meant to make `ViewController` a `UIWebViewDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a NIB? Because you are using an `IBOutlet` in your header file, which would suggest you have a NIB hooked up to it. In which case your web view will already be created, and you don't need the `alloc/init` call.

Also, why are you doing this:

```
@protocol UIWebViewDelegate;
```

...`@protocol` is used when you want to declare a protocol, not when you want to inidicate a class conforms to it. Perhaps take a quick look over Apple's documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Comment: Ok. I have done what u have said,and it doesn't work yet. I also have to say that I can't connect the IBOutlet UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate> *webView ; in the nib file, why?